# SQL Server - How to PIVOT multi value of same key

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to PIVOT a column which have multi values with same Key.
For instance, we have table

```
ID   FieldName FieldValue 
1    Name       Jack
1    Country    Auz     
1    PostCode   1234
1    Name       Jhon
2    Name       Leo
2    Country    USA
2    PostCode   2345
```

I want to get the result table after pivot:

```
ID  Name  Country  PostCode
1   Jack  Auz      1234
1   Jhon  Auz      1234
2   Leo   USA      2345
```

I have used code with pivot function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ID, FieldName, FieldValue
   FROM Table
 ) AS p
PIVOT 
(
   MAX(FieldValue)
   FOR FieldName IN ([Name], [Country], [PostCode])
) AS pvt
```

From the above code, The result table will only get one record for ID '1', I think this may due to the function of 'MAX' used. Is there any way to show two records by using any other function to solve it?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no way to associate the first three rows as one record, because there is no such thing as "the first three rows".  Do you have a column that can be used for specifying which rows go together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unusual situation in your data because ID 1 has 2 names associated with it, and you want both to share the other attributes such as postcode etc. For this you can use an `apply` operator to return 1 or more names for each ID, and then `group by` the combination of `id` and `name`.

```
SELECT
    id
  , Name
  , MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'Country' THEN fieldvalue END) AS Country
  , MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'Postcode' THEN fieldvalue END) AS Postcode
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*, ca.Name
    FROM mytable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            FieldValue AS Name
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t.id = t2.id
        AND t2.FieldName = 'Name'
    ) AS ca
WHERE FieldName IN ('Country','PostCode')
) t
GROUP BY
    id
  , name
;
```

also see:  https://rextester.com/GKOK78960

result:

```
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|    | id | Name | Country | Postcode |
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|  1 |  1 | Jack | Auz     |     1234 |
|  2 |  1 | Jhon | Auz     |     1234 |
|  3 |  2 | Leo  | USA     |     2345 |
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
```

note that using `cross apply` is a bit like an `inner join`; if there is no name associated to an id, that id will not be returned by the query above. If there is a need for an id without name use `outer apply` instead (as this is similar to `left join`).

As an alternative, you could use `pivot` like so:

```
SELECT id, name, [Country], [PostCode]
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*, ca.Name
    FROM mytable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            FieldValue AS Name
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t.id = t2.id
        AND t2.FieldName = 'Name'
    ) AS ca
    WHERE FieldName IN ('Country','PostCode')
 ) AS p
PIVOT 
(
   MAX(FieldValue)
   FOR FieldName IN ([Country], [PostCode])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is where I always feel confused as the data itself is quite unusual. Your solution is fabulous, but it will get complicated if there are more FieldName are associated. For example, now ID 1 has 2 names associated with it which can produce two row records for ID 1. What if ID 1 also has 2 countries associated with it, which should produce 2*2 =4 row records for ID 1. If There are more associations, this will make your coding more complex??

Comment: I would suggest that your data model is flawed, but assuming it is what it is, the approach can be expanded. Yes that is likely to increase the complexity but not enormously.

Comment: Yes, the model is not friendly at all. Your coding is so elegant, and I think here we may not need to include the 'FieldName In' as Case statement already check the fieldName. Previously I have come up with LEFT OUTER JOIN another with multi values. Both works fine, anyway, really appreciated for your help. Thank you so much for your time!!!!

Comment: The `where clause` could be omitted but then you would be processing rows you don't need to process, so it is there for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have tried the way 'Cross Apply' you mentioned above, but it takes much more time than 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'. I tried 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' with filter fieldName = 'name' to get the two names associated with ID1, which takes much less time for large amount of data.